# Stop displaying Popup On every page refresh

Tags: browser, button, popup, back

I need to stop displaying the Modal Popup Extender on page refresh and when browser back button is clicked.Please suggest me to find out the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I take it you're talking javascript?

You probably need to save a cookie after the first 'show'. Then check this each time - if it's present, don't show it again.

Comment: Hi adam, thanks for your quick reply.I am displaying Modal pop-up extender from code behind using C#. Could you please more precise on this.Sample code on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry I can't, C# isn't my area. You may have to read the manual.

Comment: K..thanks and could you please tell me which event will be fired on click of browser back button and how to handle those event.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the Modal Popup Extender is, but the standard procedure is as follows:

Once you opened your popup, you should set a cookie to remember you already opened it.
Next time you come across this piece of code, you have to check for the cookie first and skip opening the popup if it's there.

Comment: Hi kroimon,Thanks for the suggestion and i hope it helps me to solve the issue.I have to work around on this.